# CSS: input, span и span с картинкой должны быть на одной строке

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

У меня есть такой компонент для реакта, представляющий элемент списка:

```
import React from "react";

const TodoItem = ({ text, done }) => (
    <div className="todo-view">
        <input type="checkbox" className="todo-checkbox" />
        <span className="todo-content" tabIndex="0">{text}</span>
        <span className="todo-remove-icon"></span>
    </div>
);

export default TodoItem;
```

Его внешний вид должен быть таким: на одной строке расположен флажок (слева), текст (посередине) и иконка (справа). Я пытаюсь сделать это так:

```
.todo-remove {
    position: relative;
    right: 0;
    top: 12px;
}

.todo-remove-icon {
    background: url('remove.png') no-repeat;
    display: block;
    height: 16px;
    opacity: 0.6;
    width: 23px;
}
```

Результат не такой, какой я хочу. Флажок и текст находятся на одной строке, но картинка отрисовывается на следующей строке. Как мне написать стили, чтобы все три этих элемента были на одной строке?

Как мне задать фиксированную длину такого элемента списка, чтобы эта длина не зависела от размера содержимого и была постоянной? При этом нужно, чтобы флажок был точно у левого края, текст по центру, а иконка точно у правого края.

Метод render() в главном компоненте:

```
render() {
    let todos = this.state.items.map((item) => ({ text: item, done: false}));
    return (
      <div className="todo-app">

        <label class="todo-label" for="new_todo">
          What do you want to do today?
        </label>

        <input type="text" id="new_todo" class="todo-input" />

        <div className="todo-list">
          <TodoList items={todos} />
        </div>

      </div>
    );
```

Comment: можно без реакта пример? т.к. реакт jsx, там разницы практически не будет, так что готовый (даже неправильный) пример, если не сложно.

Comment: Вот пример как должно быть. Строки списка фиксированной длины, все части одного элемента списка расположены на одной строке. https://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/app/app-todo.html

Answer (score 1):

Используйте `flex`:

```
.todo-view {
    display: flex; 
}
.todo-remove {
    // не нуюно стилей тут
}
```

Так как по умолчанию у `flex` элемента применяеться свойство `flex-direction: row` то вы получите желаемый результат.